# Troubleshooting Polkadot.js Recognition of Prefunded Dev Accounts on a Network Using EthereumSignature

Tags: polkadot-js, ethereum

I've made some changes to my blockchain setup recently. I switched the signature over to EthereumSignature, which changed my AccountId to an H160 size. Thankfully, I can still use scripts to manage balances and move funds between accounts.

I also set up four prefunded accounts on the dev node for testing. But here's where I hit a snag. Polkadot.js doesn't seem to be recognizing these prefunded dev accounts.

Anyone else run into this or have any ideas on how to fix it? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

---

The 4 prefunded account are defined as such:

```
AccountId::from(hex!("f24FF3a9CF04c71Dbc94D0b566f7A27B94566cac")),
AccountId::from(hex!("3Cd0A705a2DC65e5b1E1205896BaA2be8A07c6e0")),
AccountId::from(hex!("798d4Ba9baf0064Ec19eB4F0a1a45785ae9D6DFc")),
AccountId::from(hex!("773539d4Ac0e786233D90A233654ccEE26a613D9")),
```

What polkadot.js shows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps actually does have a dedicated set of ethereum-style dev accounts and it does know how to make ethereum-style signatures. The tricky part is that it only enables this feature on a few hard-coded chain spec names.

Check out https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/e55b9fc67b0dc1f36f2123948fb4a8f18cdc7a38/packages/apps-config/src/settings/ethereumChains.ts#L4 for the hard-coded list.

If you are building a production chain, you could open a PR to add your spec name to that list. But if you are just developing and experimenting, you could consider changing your spec name to one that is already on the list. I used `frontier-template` and now Apps is working for me!

[image]

I would love it if there were some way to manually tell Apps to use the ethereum-style signatures and accounts. I've opened a feature request for that here https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/9632

Answer (score 1):

There is no recognition logic, just hardcoded values

https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/master/packages/keyring/src/testing.ts

So you just should update the addresses of prefunded accounts to match the hardcoded pairs.

Comment: Nice! It appears that Ethereum hardcoded addresses are also in existence. These are seemingly utilized exclusively when the keyring is of the Ethereum type, as evidenced here: 
https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/456eaeeb945875889ccfe157d93fbb67c96579ca/packages/keyring/src/testing.ts#L134

Any insights on how polkadot.js might be capable of identifying when it is operating on an Ethereum signature node?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that polkadot.js just show some well known keys in accounts when connecting to a development node, not necessarily the ones you have prefunded in your genesis config.

I must be missing some details, but I think it works this way.